# How to implement NullText in a TextBlock with Binding?

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to implement a "NullText" behavior for a TextBlock that is bound to a property in a ViewModel. When that property in the ViewModel is null or empty, I would like to display gray italic text something like "*No Data*". I'd like this to follow MVVM pattern but I am lost...

**Update**
So after playing around with the solution James Webster suggested, I got it to work like this...

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    <c:NullOrEmptyValueConverter x:Key="NullOrEmptyValueConverter" Text="(No Data)"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

 ...     

<TextBlock Name="SerialNumberTextBlock" Text="{Binding Path=SerialNumber, Converter={StaticResource NullOrEmptyValueConverter}}">
    <TextBlock.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=SerialNumberTextBlock, Path=Text}" Value="(No Data)">
                    <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
               </DataTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Resources>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: What's your existing view and view model code?

Comment: Actually, the ViewModel is an ObservableCollection of an object that is itself observable. This collection is then bound to an ItemsControl. Then in the ItemsControl.Template, I have a TextBlock bound to a property of the item in the collection. If that property is empty or null, I want "No Data" to show in the ItemsControl in the View.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend implementing an `IValueConverter`; if the source value is not null or empty, then pass it through to the TextBlock. If the source value is null or empty, then render your chosen text.

```
public class NullValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string str = (string)value;
        if (str.IsNullOrWhitespace())
        {
            return "No Data";
        }
        return str;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ... //An empty implementation I expect...
    }
}
```

However I have just realised that you want to set the style as well... hmmm, probably a `DataTrigger` that sets the style if the value is 'No Data' required I expect;

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SomeProperty, Converter={StaticResource keyToNullValueConverter}">
    <TextBlock.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Text}" Value="No Data">
            <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </TextBlock.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

Something along those lines might work.

Comment: +1, but you should fix this: `string str = (DateTime)value;` ;)

Comment: I like this idea. I will have to give it a try!

Comment: I keep getting this exception:

A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Triggers collection members must be of type EventTrigger.

Comment: Ok, after playing around with it for a while I got it to work...see my edited original post

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't need to create Converter Class, you can simply write your style code like this.

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">             
<Style.Triggers>                 
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=SerialNumberTextBlock, Path=Text}" Value="{x:Null}">                     
<Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
</DataTrigger>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=SerialNumberTextBlock, Path=Text}" Value="{x:Static System:String.Empty}">                     
<Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
</DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>         
</Style>
```

Note :- You need to include the system namespace as

```
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Comment: What would you do to set an alternate text, e.g. "No Data" ?

Comment: Add another setter on each DatatTrigger to set the required text.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to bind to a property that looks thus

```
    private string _textBlockText;
    public string TextBlockText
    {
        get
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_textBlockText))
            {
                return "No Data";
            }
            return _textBlockText;
        }
        set
        {
            _textBlockText = value;
        }
    }
```

and then use the XAML that James has mentioned for styling. Saves the need for a converter.

Comment: I think this would work in a single instance but when there are multiple TextBlocks and values to apply the same NullText to, I think the converter approach is better. Thanks anyway though!

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party, but here is my answer.

```
<TextBox >
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding MyText, TargetNullValue=No data}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyText}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyText}" Value="{x:Static System:String.Empty}">
                    <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding MyText}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

My answer assumes that you want the default text to disappear on focus, which is more in line how inputs with default text usually behave. Also this works only for null values. If you need a check for string empty or additional logic, you could instead use a converter like in other provided answers. The key idea is, that you remove null value text or converter in the binding when control gains focus and thus only display the default text when control has no focus. This also prevents the default value flowing back to your view model.

DataTriggers part for font style was kindly borrowed from pchajer's answer.